# How can I re-render react-component when I setState using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to write a component that update timeline every few seconds, so I use a for loop like this and use `setTimeout` to make the interval more obvious:

```
let tmp = this.state.colors;
// colors is an array
for(let i = 0 ; i < 4; i++){
    if(tmp[i]=="blue"){
        tmp[i]="green";
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(tmp);
            this.mapped.setState({
                colors: tmp
            });
        }.bind({mapped:this}), 2000);
    }
}
```

But it seems that it can't re-render my component at once,I want my component update the timeline every two seconds, but it just re-render one time.

And I know that react process all the `setStates()` after the `eventHandler` has completed.I tried to use `forceUpdate` although I know it's not discouraged, but it doesn't work.

So what's the best way to re-render my component?

Any help would be great appreciated.

---

**Update**

Thanks @andre-lee.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            tmp[i] = "green";
            this.setState({
                colors: tmp
            });
        }.bind(this), 2000 * (i + 1));
    }
```

The above code works.

Comment: how do you know it's not updating the same _tmp_ each time? (and thus nothing). throw a `console.log(tmp)` in there

Comment: Since the for-loop is very fast, you should use `2000 * i` for your setTimeout. I just posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a draft based on your code snippet as following,
http://codepen.io/andretw/pen/JWmYGo

There are two major changes in my draft.

1. You should use `2000 * i` for your **setTimeout**. Or you can use setInterval and clear it later.
2. Change the color **in the callback function** in your setTimeout.

Comment: `2000 * 0 = 0; 2000 * 1 = 2000; 2000 * 2 = 4000; 2000 * 3 = 6000;` - why would he need to do `2000 * i`?

Comment: Since you do the setTimeout in a for-loop, all of them: setTimeout(func, 0), setTimeout(func, 2000), setTimeout(func, 4000), setTimeout(func, 6000) are doing almost the same time. If you don't `* i`, you will get setTimeout(func, 2000), setTimeout(func, 2000), setTimeout(func, 2000), setTimeout(func, 2000). They will do it almost the same time.

Comment: You can fork my codepen and remove `* i` to see the console.log() and you will get to know it better.

Comment: I understand, but since a timeout is `0`, it can be excluded from a `setTimeout` block and later ones included in...

Comment: You can use `i + 1` or increase your i and starts from 1, right?

Comment: I didn't use `i + 1` or change the init value of `i` since I don't want to change many of your code can help you get clearer of what I thought.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are not @McGrady. But yes, I just simplified the answer and pointed out what I thought the issues are.